# Chamar um método utilizando a seleção de Spinner

Tags: android, spinners

É possivel chamar um método utilizando um `Spinner` do android?

Preciso que seja selecionado a opção e com base nessa opção selecionado preciso mandar um `request` para o `webservice`, e este me retornar as outras opções do `Spnnier` em seguida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Através do `setOnItemSelectedListener`:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // SEU CÓDIGO 
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
         // SEU CÓDIGO 
    }

});
```

[Segue a documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html)

Comment: Ǹossa é bem parecido com o do ListView. Vou testar aqui ai já valido sua resposta.